# From a magento observer how can I tell action type

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How can I know if an action is front end or backend from within the code of an observer for the controller_action_layout_render_before event ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns `true` if currently in backend.

```
Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a print of the object observer to log file to see if you can find any data which acts as a clue to what you need:

> ```
> Mage::log("observer object:" . print_r($observer, true));
> ```

I think there may be a data field which contains the event which fired the observer from there.    Please post back your findings!

Hope this helps.

Comment: No need to print_r an object before passing it into the log. Magenta will auto expand it for you.